# When binding parameter is null, consider it as "select all"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT documents.abc FROM documents WHERE documents.def IN ""
```

Here's a sample code and double quote means the binding parameter. Parameter is the keyword from user's search work.

Currently, if user doesn't put any keyword, this code doesn't return any result either.

I want to select all documents.abc if parameter is null or empty.

Can you help this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
SELECT documents.abc FROM documents WHERE $param IS NULL OR $param = '' OR documents.def IN ($param)
```

Comment: Well, you save my day my friend! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'll gratefully select your answer after 5 minute!

Comment: How kind of you! I'll make new question after few minutes and I wish you could help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011049/is-there-something-wrong-with-this-mysql-code This is the question. I'll be glad if you help this one, too!!